# Can I use xCode accessibility label for data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a storyboard to place around 100 images in a UIScrollView.  I'm putting data for each image in the "Accessibility Label" place in the xCode panel to avoid me having to map the name of each image to a certain data label.  Is this safe?  Are there any possibilities that this data may not be available to me on any device at any moment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's safe, but it's bad practice. Blind of hard-of-sight users will have those data labels read aloud to them if they click on the image. As an alternative, you could add the data label as a User Defined Runtime attribute